# undefined local variable or method `signed_in_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a custom confirmation method upon sign up built on top of Devise Signup

I'm following the guidelines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984977/email-confirmation-in-rails-without-using-any-existing-authentication-gems-plugi) and this is my Registration Controller, overwritten:

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :create, :edit, :update, :create_by_user ]
# before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def new
    super
end

def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    puts "what is resource_name: #{resource_name}"
    resource.confirmed ||= false
    resource.confirmation_code ||= create_random_pass
    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        # set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        UserMailer.send_simple_message(resource).deliver
      else
        # set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
end


def edit
    super
end


def update
    super
end


def confirmation
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end


def confirm
  ## handles the confirmation
  puts "The params: #{params[:confirmation_code]}"
  puts "Hello"
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  if user.confirmed == false
    puts "It's false"
    redirect_to '/'
  elsif user.confirmed == true
    puts "It's true"
  else
    puts "It's nil"
  end
end
```

and I match the routes such as:

```
      devise_scope :user do 
        root to: 'static_pages#home'
        match '/sessions/user',                                           to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
        match '/users/newuser',                                           to: 'registrations#create_by_user', via:[:post, :get]
        match '/users/:user_id/confirmation/',                            to: 'registrations#confirmation', via:  :get
        match '/users/:user_id/confirm',                                  to: 'registrations#confirm', via: :post
```

end

when I submit the form in '/users/:user_id/confirmation' I get an error:

```
NameError in UsersController#update
undefined local variable or method `signed_in_user' for #<UsersController:0x00000005696e00>
```

I clearly don't fully understand what devise is doing, because I don't get why he calls the Users controller instead of Registration Controller

EDIT:

My UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    3.times { @user.accounts.build }
  end

  def create
    # @user = params[:user] ? User.new(user_params) : User.new_guest
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @account = @user.accounts.new(account_params)
    if @user.save && @account.save
      sign_in @user

      ##flash[:success] = "Welcome to the HighTide!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  ## I tried also putting in here the logic of the confirmation code
  def confirmation
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def confirm
    puts "The params: #{params[:confirmation_code]}"
    puts "Hello"
    # self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
  #     prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if user.confirmed == false
      puts "It's false"
      redirect_to '/'
    elsif user.confirmed == true
      puts "It's true"
    else
      puts "It's nil"
    end
  end


  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def user_params
      # params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
      #                              :password_confirmation, accounts_attributes: [:id, :title])
      params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, accounts_attributes: [:id, :title])
    end

end
```

Comment: Post your `UsersController`.

Comment: Post your routes file too where you have mapped the RegistrationsController with devise

Comment: Updated, gee what did I do to get 2 downvotes?

Comment: `signed_in_user` in `UsersController` is not defined.  What should `signed_in_user` do?  Are you trying to authenticate the user?  If so use `authenticate_user!` instead of `signed_in_user`.

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira, I'm not sure why you got the downvotes, neither from me.

Comment: I'm not trying to authenticate, but since I'm using Devise Registration Controller, I don't understand why he goes to UsersController#update

Answer (score 0):

Use authenticate_user instead of signed_in_user. This is required for devise configuration.

You have a before action call in users controller. That expects a method called signed_in_user. Why do you have that there? This got nothing to do with devise.

Comment: I did comment out that part and I don't have any errors, but he redirects to UsersController#update, when the submit button on the form redirects to Registration#confirm method...I don't get it

Comment: That's because of sign_up(user, user) in confirm method. It probably redirects restful to user controller. And hence goes to update method of user controller. I'm not sure.

Comment: I have the same behaviour without that line of code (that either way didn't make sense)

Comment: I figured what was causing that, in the form helper he was redirecting to the UsersController